Condition for a car moving with a constant velocity
I seek your help with this simple yet confusing problem. The question says:

A car is moving with a constant velocity 10m/s. Which one is correct?

No force is acting on the car
The force applied by the car is equal to the friction force


Now, I would go with (1) for the following reasons:

If no force is acting on the car, the net force is essentially 0 meeting the requirement of Newton's 1st law
While the second one looks like a more specific scenario for this, the question doesn't omit the possibility of other forces (e.g air resistance). Moreover, the coefficient of friction and hence the friction force is definite. For a different velocity, it can't be equal to the force applied by the car.

But some are saying it would be (2). What will be the correct answer?

(1) does not say that no net force is acting, just that no forces applies to body at all, so you are incorrect.

The question is crap. I can imagine a teacher arguing that answer 1 is correct, and I can just as easily imagine a teacher arguing that answer 2 is correct. Your best bet is to look back through your lecture notes, and hope to find something similar that the teacher said—something that will give you a clue as to what they really mean by "no force," what they really mean by "force applied by the car," etc.

@SolomonSlow Yea :) But the problem is, this is a question from our board level exam (Idk what you call these, it's a national public exam we are required to take). So it completely depends on whoever marks our answers.

The question is closed, so I can't answer, but I would say (1) is incorrect because it doesn't really match with what we understand of the meaning of "a car moving."  In our usual understanding there's air friction present, so there is a force.  If there is no air friction, like Elon's Telsa that's currently in orbit, there's still gravity.  To have no forces would require the car to be in such deep space that we can't recognize any gravitational nor drag forces.  That just doesn't sound like "a car moving" to me.  And even in that extreme, we're just syaing the forces are very weak.

For something to move at constant velocity means the NET force acting on it is zero, and not necessarily that there are no forces acting on it.
The force responsible for pushing the car forward is the static friction force exerted on the drive wheels by the road. Forces opposing the motion of the car are various dissipative friction forces (mechanical, air drag). When the two are equal, the net force acting on the car is zero and the car moves at constant velocity. See the figure below.
Bottom line: No force is a sufficient but not necessary condition for the car to move at constant velocity, whereas a net force of zero is both a necessary and sufficient condition,
Hope this helps.


What if there was a force at the beginning that made it reach that velocity (the question assumes it's already moving with a constant velocity)? Afterwards, no force acting on it will maintain that right?

@Abrar The last thing you said is always true, even if there was "no force at the beginning". But still, zero NET force acting on it (which is completely different from NO force acting on it) will also maintain whatever the initial velocity is, as the answer said. Said differently: If there is no force acting on something, you can conclude that it stays at constant velocity. However, if something does stay at constant velocity, you cannot NOT conclude that there are no forces acting on it.

@Abrar of course a net force was necessary to accelerate the car to its velocity. It was the static friction force between the road and tires. But after that the static friction force is opposed be other friction forces (mechanical in the car, and external air friction) for a net force of zero and constant velocity. So choice 1 is wrong. But choice 2 is poorly worded

@BobD Alright! But one more thing. The question statement itself doesn't mention any friction either from the road or air. If that's true, no force would be there I guess (once accelerated)? In that case, doesn't the first one makes more sense?

@Abrar You know, unless the car is moving in a vacuum,  there is an air drag force opposing the motion of the vehicle. So how can you say there is NO force acting on the car. Do you understand that the force enabling the car to move forward is the static friction force from the road?

@Abrar See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653204/how-does-friction-accelerate-a-car-after-rest

@BobD I think I didn't explain it well. I am, now, considering a frictionless environment as the question doesn't mention any. As the car is already moving with a constant velocity which was accelerated at the beginning by whatever method (static friction is the most realistic reason). Now, once it's already accelerated, afterwards, if there is no friction at all, there won't be any force, right?

@Abrar I think you have this backwards. Unless they specifically say to ignore friction, then you have to assume a realistic scenario for a moving car in which, at a minimum, involves air drag.

@BobD Most of our questions assume no friction actually, but yea, I get that, for a real situation choice 2 is more appropriate.

@Abrar See update to my answer with more details on the forces acting on the car.
